# Regex in perl array

Tags: regex, perl

I have a array in Perl which has values like this :

```
$Array[0] = "[a][b][c] good bad";
$Array[1] = "[d] apple";
$Array[2] = "[e][f] mango ";
$Array[3] = "[g] capgemini";
```

I need a regular exp which finds all the text between `[]`.
I have written this :

```
my @matched = grep {$_ ne ""} map { m/\[(.*?)\]/; $1; } @Array;
```

However this finds the first match only, like `a` from `$Array[0]`, `e` from `$Array[2]`.
I want to get all of them like `a,b,c` from `$Array[0]`.

Comment: Do you actually have a hash reference in each array element, or did you put some kind of quotation around the curly brackets `{ }` ?

Comment: I used {} so as not to confuse with []. It is a array only and each line within " " is its element.

Comment: From now on please post your example data as either valid Perl code, or as a well recognized data format. You could use the output of [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper), [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer), [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON), [YAML](http://p3rl.org/YAML::Any).

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of anonymous hashes and omission of sigils is confusing. This works for me, though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @Array;
$Array[0]= "[a][b][c] good bad";
$Array[1]= "[d] apple";
$Array[2]= "[e][f] mango ";
$Array[3]= "[g] capgemini";
my @matched = map { m/\[(.*?)\]/g } @Array;
print Dumper \@matched;
```

The main trick is to use the `/g` option for global matching and letting the matching return all the matches.

Comment: We can have some like [], which is empty. But in our final array we dont want empty elements, so we can use the grep too I think.

Comment: @SomnathPaul Use `.+?` instead to avoid capturing empty elements. Or avoid using non-greedy capture and use `[^]]+`